# database insert not working and database functionality potential misunderstanding

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to make a database for a shop - where the customers can purchase products and pay for them (for testing purposes not official so I have took naive approach) and also view their previous orders. Staff can confirm and edit the orders as well as check and add stock.
Customers will pic two fields - preferences and avatar -that will be used to display ads at the side
I have created a database for this, my first attempt at making a complex database by the by, and I am unaware if I am on the right track, could anyone give me some pointers or improvement advise.
Also when trying to insert data into the tables I get an error message saying 
" No row was updated
he data in row 1 was not commited
error source: .NetSqlClient Data Provider.
Error message: cant insert the value NULL into column 'adid' table 'dbo.consumer' column dosent allow nulls. Insert fails."

This is despite attempting to enter data, it dosent take any input, and all the other fields in every table take the input but dont store it and give a similar error message
[database diag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laah7.png)ram ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laah7.png)

here is an example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiIKU.png)

```
customerid  int Unchecked
forename    varchar(50) Unchecked
surname varchar(50) Unchecked
addrss  varchar(50) Unchecked
vipstatus   int Unchecked
access  varchar(5)  Unchecked
username    varchar(50) Unchecked
password    varchar(50) Unchecked
preferences varchar(10) Unchecked
avatar  varchar(10) Unchecked
paymentid   int Unchecked
adid    int Unchecked
        Unchecked
```

when i copy my table and paste it this is what the output is, to get a jist as to what Im working with. 
If anyone can have a look and help fix or advise on a fix the insert error and any database functionality errors, that would be great

[insert error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q43QG.png)

Comment: what is the insert query that you are making

Comment: on the second image, you can see the data above the insert message, I am manually inserting it

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: why wont the database accept any input? and any improvements on the database design

Answer (score 0):

In schema i see foreign key between table "customer" and "ads".

Before insert data to "Customer" table insert row to "Ads" table.
Next when you inserting data to table Customer in column "ADID" you should insert interested "adid" value from table "Ads". Value in column "Customer"."adid" must not be null.

Comment: It allows me insert data into 'ads' but when trying to add data into the customer table after, i recieve the same error, and it dosent allow me to insert any value into the 'adid' field in the customer table when editing

Comment: you are sure filed customer.adid is not null? In your screenshot from SQL management studio not see this field. Maybe try write insert manually in SQL code and check results? Or rollback old changes and try again insert?

Comment: I have updated the post with a picture of my attempt at inserting data, hope this will help clear up the problem, all the fields in this table are not null too

Comment: First - you missing column paymentid in statement. Add it column for your insert becouse all of column in customer is not null

Second your insert strings in all column - in your table description i see int column, to this colimn insert numbers not string example change value &#39;2&#39; to 2

Comment: paymentid was left out as its auto_increment, and i have got it able to insert data into all the fields due to your help, except still original problem of adid displaying NULL and not changing its value or allowing the value to be altered

Comment: You insert value '2' to customer.adid? Try insert 2

In table ads you must records with adid equals 2